# jQuery sort list by list content date or alphabetically

Tags: jquery, date, sorting, alphabetical

I want to sort an unordered list by the contents of the list items. By default I want it to sort by the date, with the option to sort it alphabetically by the name.

```
<select id="test">
    <option selected="selected" value="date">Date</option>
    <option value="alphabetically">Alphabetically</option>
</select>
<ul id="list">
  <li><p class="name">Peter</p><span class="date">10.12.12</span></li>
  <li><p class="name">Mary</p><span class="date">06.01.13</span></li>
  <li><p class="name">Paul</p><span class="date">19.12.12</span></li>
  <li><p class="name">Allen</p><span class="date">21.12.12</span></li>
  <li><p class="name">James</p><span class="date">03.01.13</span></li>
  <li><p class="name">Vicki</p><span class="date">12.01.13</span></li>
  <li><p class="name">Brock</p><span class="date">01.01.13</span></li>
  <li><p class="name">Dana</p><span class="date">31.12.12</span></li>
  <li><p class="name">Frank</p><span class="date">16.12.12</span></li>
  <li><p class="name">Gil</p><span class="date">09.01.13</span></li>
  <li><p class="name">Helen</p><span class="date">14.01.13</span></li>
</ul>
```

My attempt so far:

```
function sortUnorderedList(ul, sortDescending) {
  if (typeof ul == "string") ul = document.getElementById(ul);
  var lis = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  var vals = [];
  for (var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++)
  vals.push(lis[i].innerHTML);
  vals.sort();
  if (sortDescending) vals.reverse();
  for (var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++)
  lis[i].innerHTML = vals[i];
}
$(document).ready(function () {
  var desc = false;
  document.getElementById("test").onchange = function () {
    sortUnorderedList("list", desc);
    desc = !desc;
    return false;
  };
});
function sortDescending(a, b) {
  var date1 = $(a).find(".date").text();
  date1 = date1.split('.');
  date1 = new Date(date1[2], date1[1] - 1, date1[0]);
  var date2 = $(b).find(".date").text();
  date2 = date2.split('.');
  date2 = new Date(date2[2], date2[1] - 1, date2[0]);
  return date1 < date2 ? 1 : -1;
}
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('ul > li').sort(sortDescending).appendTo('ul');
});
```

When the page loads the list is sorted by the value of the "date" span content, on select menu change it sorts the list alphabetically. But when I change it back to "Date" the list dates aren't sorted correctly in descending order.

http://jsfiddle.net/s2JxC/

Can anybody help out? I'd like the alphabetical sorting to sort by the class "name". In the same way as the date sorts by the class "date".

Cheers, JV

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a big logical flaw in your code. I have updated your jsfiddle. (http://jsfiddle.net/s2JxC/4/)

You have a function `sortUnorderedList()` that sorts Alphabetically (ascending and descending) and you have a function `sortDescending()` that sorts your list using the Date (always descending).

I have made it so that it always sorts Alphabetically when you click Alphabetically and always sorts by Date (descending) when you select Date form the dropdown.

The rest is just up to you, how you want it to actually work. I hope this helps!

EDIT:  As requested [jsfiddle.net/s2JxC/7](http://jsfiddle.net/s2JxC/7) <-- sorts alphabetically by ".name" when you click on alphabetically. and sorts descending by ".date" when you click date.

---

What you were doing before was that you were sorting by date (descending) on page load. And alphabetically when you clicked alphabetically and un-alphabetically? (descending) when you clicked on date.

Comment: You could have coded it a lot better by the way by doing something similar to your sortDescending() function and making it more generic. Let me know if you need help with that.

Comment: Thanks @sanchit but I need it to sort from the class "name" for alphabetical sorting.

Comment: You are practically already doing that... regardless.  Here. http://jsfiddle.net/s2JxC/7/ Mark this as answered please.